# How do I find the sum of the series $\sum a_k$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do I find the sum of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ when $a_k=\int_k^{k+1} xe^{-x}dx$? I know there are theorems saying if if the series converges, the sum of the derivative of the series also converges, but I don't know what the relation is for the sums themselves.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$\sum_{k\ge 1}a_k=\int_1^\infty xe^{-x}\,dx$$